# Prevent Powershell ForEach from Adding Superfluous Quotes

Tags: powershell

I have a colon-delimited CSV like so,

```
Mailbox:Users
AcmeCorp:("jsmith","trex")
XyzCorp:("sjobs","bfranklin")
```

It is then added to a variable:

```
$file = import-csv file.csv -delimiter :
```

Now, I work with it:

```
foreach ($record in $file) {
    $record.Users | % { get-aduser $_ }
}
```

`write-host` in the foreach loop reports `$record.Users` is `("jsmith","trex")`

However, `get-aduser` (or other cmdlets) complains that it cannot find an object with identity `'("jsmith","trex")'`.

How do you prevent foreach from adding single quotes to parameter?

I've already tried Users like `"sjobs","bfranklin"` but import-csv strips the double quotes off of `sjobs`

Or better, how do you pass a list of users to foreach?

PowerShell version 4

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are not being added by PS. They are right there in your file. Here is a snippet to give you a start in the right direction:

```
$file = Import-csv file.csv -delimiter ':'
foreach($row in $file){
    foreach($user in $row.Users.split(',')){
        Get-ADUser ($user.replace('(','').Replace('"','').replace(')',''))
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, double quotes are in the file, however single quotes do get added.  Thanks for the tip, a hack with .split was used as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you think that you are importing an array of strings as the value of `Users`, but you in fact are just importing a single string. There are a couple of options here, using the `split` method as you have already discovered:

```psh
$file = import-csv file.csv -delimiter ':'
ForEach($Record in $File){
    $Record.Users.Trim('()').Split(',') | ForEach{
        Get-ADUser $_.Trim('"')
    }
}
```

So the `$Record.Users.Trim('()')` removes the parenthesis from the string. Then it uses `.Split(',')` to split the string into an array of strings. Then it passes that to an inner ForEach loop when gets the ADUser from each string, after removing the quotes from around it (with `.Trim('"')`).

Alternatively you could have one user per line, so your CSV would appear like:

```psh
Mailbox:User
AcmeCorp:jsmith
AcmeCorp:trex
XyzCorp:sjobs
XyzCorp:bfranklin
```

Then after importing the CSV you could just group by the mailbox if needed, say, to add users per mailbox or something:

```psh
$File = Import-CSV C:\Path\To\File.csv -delimiter ':'
$MBGroups = $File | Group Mailbox
ForEach($Record in $MBGroups){
    $Mailbox = $Record.Name
    $Users = $Record.Group | ForEach{Get-ADUser $_.User}
    $Users | ForEach{Set-ADUser -mail ($_.samaccountname+"@"+$Mailbox+".com")}
}
```